# ffmpeg - Drawing rotated text on video with complex filters takes a very long time

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to overlap different text pieces on some placeholders in a video, and I am using multiple complex filters of the following type:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/input.mp4 -filter_complex  \
    "color=black@0:100x100,format=yuva444p[c]; \
    [c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv31]; \
    [ct]setsar=1,split=1[t31];\
    [t31]\
    drawtext=text='text':x='main_w/2-text_w/2+70':y=210:fontsize="100":fontcolor=black,\
    drawtext=text='text2':x='main_w/2-text_w/2+75':y=340:fontsize="100":fontcolor=black,\
    rotate=-0.07:ow=rotw(-0.07):oh=roth(-0.07):c=black@0[txta31]; \
    [mv31][txta31]overlay=enable='between(t, 0, 1.15)':x='min(0,-H*sin(-0.07))':y='min(0,W*sin(-0.07))':shortest=1" \
       ~/Desktop/result.mp4 -y1
```

My goal is to write differently rotated texts on different time intervals in the video. The problem is that at about 10-12 [t31]-like pieces(here is an example of only one command), the rendering time of the video is twice the time of the video, whereas drawing straight horizontal text takes about 10-20% of the total video length (examples, for a 1 minute video, it takes about 8-10 seconds to write straight horizontal text, and about 2 minutes to write the same amount of text, but inclined with an angle). Is there any better way to do these multiple rotated text bits with more performance?

Comment: Provide full command and log with formatting.

Comment: I edited the comand and I made it shorter, full comand have more texts and overlays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any better way to do these multiple rotated text bits with more performance?

Using the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter will be faster and arguably simpler. Example [ASS](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/) file:

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by Aegisub 3.2.2
; http://www.aegisub.org/
Title: Default Aegisub file
ScriptType: v4.00+
WrapStyle: 0
ScaledBorderAndShadow: yes
YCbCr Matrix: None
PlayResX: 640
PlayResY: 480

[Aegisub Project Garbage]
Last Style Storage: Default
Video File: ?dummy:23.976000:40000:640:480:47:163:254:
Video AR Value: 1.333333
Active Line: 1

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Arial,100,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,2,2,10,10,10,1

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:01.15,Default,,0,0,0,,{\pos(400,180),\frz10}text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:01.15,Default,,0,0,0,,{\pos(400,260),\frz10}text2
```

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "subtitles=rotate.ass[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -c:a copy output
```

[image]

Comment: I am generating ASS subtitles file and I am adding a position in the pos tag, My frontend app is built on Konvajs. The coordinates which are generated from the Konva are not usable in the ASS subtitle file. Because they are not synchronized, for example: if I send the x = 400, y= 200 from the front end the text is shown in the slightly upper from the middle right of the video. but the same coordinates make the text disappear from the video. Conclusion, The cords on the frontend are slightly higher than the cords on the ASS pos tag. I have also tried the filter of W and H.

Comment: @UmairRiaz You can ask this as a new question. It will be easier to help.

Comment: Actually, there was a problem with Script resolution. The resolution of the script and video must be matched to get the exact position of the text.