# How to rotate only the text in ffmpeg and not the whole video

Tags: ffmpeg

am using this command to put text on a video

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $urlVideo $startFlags 'drawtext=fontfile=$font:text=$text:fontcolor=$color:x=$x: y=$y: fontsize=$size$enable' $endFlags " . $resultFilePath
```

so i added the rotate argument to rotate a text (rotate=0.3). so the result was that the hole file was rotated. how to rotate only the text?
thank you.

PS:am so new to ffmpeg :3

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128933/ffmpeg-drawing-rotated-text-on-video-with-complex-filters-takes-a-very-long-ti

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I think this answer is suggesting create ASS file for each text am putting? if so, this will be to much implementation in code. cus i will run this as a public telegram bot service
Thank you

Comment: Create a new transparent stream with a `color` source filter and add text to it. Rotate the stream then overlay it on your video. (Coding up ASS script can be more efficient though)

Comment: @kesh, i tried it, but i couldn't control the angle, i think the (/frz10) event has a default angle

Comment: @kesh can you please give me a command example of doing this by `color` filter as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `-vf` option expression example:

```
color=c=black@0,drawtext=text=Test Text:x=w/2:y=h/2,rotate=PI/6:fillcolor=black@0[L0];
[in][L0]overlay=shortest=true
```

For precise positioning, you can try:

- size `color` source to match your text size.
- let `rotate` to expand frame size.
- remember `rotate` rotates the frame about its center
- use `overlay`'s `x` and `y` options to place the text in its final position